# Find an element which has multiple div in Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to find an element which is like a place holder. I will draganddrop other element to this. `HTML` has

```
<div class="value1" > <div class="value2" data-id="some_number" data-aura+"value"> 
<div class="place holder"> div2, div3 > Add component </div>

<div class="row contentPanel" data-aura-render="53:56;a"><div class="col-lg-12" data-aura-rendered-by="54:56;a">
<div class="interactions siteforceDesignTimeRegion" data-region-name="content" data-allow-drop="true" data-item-id="87f9712-27f4-564-9445-fg30cf4321a7" data-aura-render="6:56;a" data-aura-class="siteforceDesignTimeRegion">
<div class="Placeholder siteRegion" data-aura-render="10:56;a" data-aura-class="forceDesignTimeEmptyRegion">Add components to this place</div>
<!--render facet: 18:56;a--></div></div></div>
```

I have tried the below in my code. It actually works in console. But its not working when I used it in code. Would be helpful if someone provides an answer with cssselector or xpath. Thanks.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'row contentPanel')]"));
```

Comment: please post the actual html, your description is too cryptic

Comment: <div class="row contentPanel" data-aura-rendered-by="53:56;a"><div class="col-lg-12" data-aura-rendered-by="54:56;a"><div class="interactions siteforceDesignTimeRegion" data-region-name="content" data-allow-drop="true" data-item-id="41f29275-27f4-465a-9445-ac30cf9088a7" data-aura-rendered-by="6:56;a" data-aura-class="siteforceDesignTimeRegion"><div class="emptyRegionPlaceholder siteforceDesignTimeEmptyRegion" data-aura-rendered-by="10:56;a" data-aura-class="siteforceDesignTimeEmptyRegion">Add components to this region (Content)
 </div><!--render facet: 18:56;a--></div></div></div>

Comment: What is the error occurred when you tried your code??

Comment: @DavidBaak it didn't allow to post the actual html..I have added here as comment..thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur it throws this error..org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: Try using `WebDriverWait` as `WebElement el = new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.row.contentPanel")));` and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comment :-

> it throws this error..org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

There could be following reasons for this `exception` as below :-

- May be when you are going to find element, it would not be present on the `DOM`, So you should implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element present on `DOM` as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf‌​ElementLocated(By.cs‌​sSelector("div.row.c‌​ontentPanel")));
  ```
- May be this element is inside any `frame/iframe`. If it is, you need to switch that `frame/iframe` before finding the desired element as below :-

  ```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

  //Wait until frame/iframe to available and then switch to it
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("your frame id or name"));

  //Now find the desired element 
  WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf‌​ElementLocated(By.cs‌​sSelector("div.row.c‌​ontentPanel")));

  //Once all your stuff done with this frame/iframe need to switch back to default for further stuff
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  ```

Comment: great it works :) I tested this in other place as our website is having some trouble now..thanks a lot